# Where are the O2 Sensors in a VW with 3 sensors?

Tags: exhaust, o2-sensor, p0420

My VW CC 2010 2.0L Sport CBFA has three oxygen sensors and two catalytic converters.
The CCTA version has 2 oxygen sensors and one catalytic converter.

Since the engine is in a transverse 4 configuration, there is only Bank 1, but I'm confused on what numbers identify which sensor.

For my car the configuration is like this.
Sensor 1 (closest to engine and on first cat) -> sensor 2 or 3 (dont know) -> cat 2 ->  sensor 2 or 3 (dont know)

In a CCTA it's easy since obviously sensor 1 is upstream and sensor 2 is downstream, but for CBFA I'm left guessing.

They also use words like downstream, center, intermediate, upstream.

Does upstream = sensor 1?
Does center = sensor 2?
Does downstream = sensor 3?

Getting code p0420 and p2096